# Adding \ before every space in a string

Tags: string, python-2.7

If I have a path in a string such as:

```
'Documents/Programming/Python scripts/'
```

I want to put a `\` after the word `Python`

Such that it looks like:

`Documents/Programming/Python\ scripts/`
How do I do that?

Comment: you have to put `'\'` after the word `'Python'` every time or single time only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) method:

```
>>> s = 'Documents/Programming/Python scripts/'
>>> s = s.replace(' ', '\ ')
>>> print s
Documents/Programming/Python\ scripts/
```

Comment: Thank you very much